# How to combine plots using only R studio plotting device?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Let's consider two plots - one in each window:

```
ggplot() + aes(x=1:10, y = 1:10) + geom_line()
```

[image]

```
ggplot() + aes(x=1:20, y = 1:20) + geom_line()
```

[image]

I'm curious if there is any possibility to create side by side plots (by for example `patchowrk::wrap_plots` or any other tools for side by side plots) by only using `r studio` device plotting. i.e. can I create side by side plot created by these two but the only information stored in r studio plotting device (i.e. no source code of plots etc)

Comment: Not without reproducing much of the functionality of `patchwork` and/or `cowplot`. Those packages are awesome and complicated and very useful because this is an often-asked question, and short of grob-editing with the `grid` (and related) package, which is prone to so many problems, there are no solutions. It shouldn't be hard to find duplicates for this question.

Comment: Many times it can be side-stepped by producing facets. From your other recent questions it sounds like you aren't interested in this approach, but it should not be ignored.

Comment: I'm unsure what the goal of this approach would be. Is it just to obfuscate the underlying objects? If so you can use `ggplotGrob(my_plot)` to get a raw-ish object that can be plotted with `grid.newpage(); grid.draw(my_ggplotgrob)`. I think you might even `cbind()` different gtables if they have the same number of elements.